# How can I free memory used by malloc() outside a function?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am trying to free the memory allocated by my getSongInfo function, I have tried using a pointer to the function call but I get an error "cannt assign int to type int*" error. Any help would be great as the current way I have seems like it may work, but I might be completely wrong. Thanks!

**Original Attempt:**

```
int *memPtr = NULL
memPtr = getSongInfo(&fillPtr[arrayCounter], tempArtist[counter], tempSong[counter]);
Gives error!
```

Current Attempt:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#pragma warning(disable:4996)

int getSongInfo(struct songInfo *pFillInfo, char *artistName, char *songName);
void printSongInfo(struct songInfo songList[10]);

struct songInfo {

    char *songArtist;
    char *songTitle;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct songInfo *fillPtr;
    struct songInfo songList[10];
    fillPtr = &songList[0];

    char tempArtist[10][30];
    char tempSong[10][30];

    int *memPtr = NULL;

    int i = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int arrayCounter = 0;
    while (counter != 10)
    {
        printf("Please enter the artist name: ");
        fgets(tempArtist[counter], sizeof(tempArtist[counter]), stdin);
        tempArtist[counter][strcspn(tempArtist[counter], "\n")] = 0;
        printf("Please enter the song name: ");
        fgets(tempSong[counter], sizeof(tempSong[counter]), stdin);
        tempSong[counter][strcspn(tempSong[counter], "\n")] = 0;

        getSongInfo(&fillPtr[arrayCounter], tempArtist[counter], tempSong[counter]);
        printf("Song and Artist Captured! \n");
        counter++;
        arrayCounter++;

    }

    printSongInfo(fillPtr);
    free(fillPtr->songArtist);
    free(fillPtr->songTitle);
}

int getSongInfo(struct songInfo *pFillInfo, char *artistName, char *songName)
{

    pFillInfo->songArtist = (char*)malloc(strlen(artistName) + 1);
    pFillInfo->songTitle = (char*)malloc(strlen(songName) + 1);


    strcpy(pFillInfo->songArtist, artistName);
    strcpy(pFillInfo->songTitle, songName);

    return 1;
}

void printSongInfo(struct songInfo songList[10])
{
    int counter = 0;


    while (counter != 10)
    {
        printf("%-35s %-35s\n", songList[counter].songArtist, songList[counter].songTitle);
        counter++;
    }

}
```

Comment: `getSongInfo()` retuns an `int`!!

Comment: `void`? now it's even more horrible.

Comment: Please make sure the code can be compiled. Fix the errors and warnings first. Why do you use `#pragma warning(disable:4996)`? You should fix the code instead of suppressing the warning.

Comment: @Bodo the code does compile, also the warning is used for warning issues with fgets only. It just states it is unsafe without the use of say scanf

Comment: I get several errors: `main.c:8:36: error: array type has incomplete element type 'struct songInfo'`, `main.c:40:16: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be`, `main.c:49:19: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete`, `main.c:54:6: error: conflicting types for 'getSongInfo'` and also warnings. Maybe you checked a different verson of the code.

Comment: Did my answer help?  If not, is there anything I can clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Your `getSongInfo` function does not return a pointer, so attempting to put the return value into a variable and then free it is pointless.  The pointers in question are inside the `struct songInfo`, specifically, the `fillPtr` variable (which is actually redundant, since `songList` and `fillPtr` point to the same location).

In addition, please be aware that `strcspn` will not always return a valid index.  If it does not find a match, it will return the length of the first argument.

I think this is more like what you are trying to do:

```
int main(void)
{
    const int numSongs = 10;

    struct songInfo songList[numSongs];

    char tempArtist[30];
    char tempSong[30];

    int i;
    int newline_idx;
    for (i = 0; i < numSongs; ++i)
    {
        printf("Please enter the artist name: ");
        fgets(tempArtist, sizeof(tempArtist), stdin);
        newline_idx = strcspn(tempArtist, "\n");
        if (newline_idx < sizeof(tempArtist))
            tempArtist[newline_idx] = 0;

        printf("Please enter the song name: ");
        fgets(tempSong, sizeof(tempSong), stdin);
        newline_idx = strcspn(tempSong, "\n");
        if (newline_idx < sizeof(tempSong))
            tempSong[newline_idx] = 0;

        getSongInfo(&songList[i], tempArtist, tempSong);
        printf("Song and Artist Captured! \n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numSongs; ++i)
    {
        free(songList[i].songArtist);
        free(songList[i].songTitle);
    }
}
```

You might consider separating the code for `free()`ing each struct into its own function.

You might also consider heeding that compiler warning instead of ignoring it, as Bodo commented.  Careless handling of strings from stdin is dangerous.